# Angular Routing through GET Query Parameters

Tags: java, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I am building an Angular application inside another, older Java, application, and the idea is that one by one, we'll be replacing each page in the java application with a corresponding Angular page. However, I'm running into a problem with handling multiple pages. The Java application serves pages the following manner
localhost:8080/app/Track?page={pageName}
I'm trying to figure out exactly how I can write a route to handle this type of pages, since Angular seems to only like directory based routes. I tried using a matcher

```
export function GTSPage(url: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, 
pageName: string): UrlMatchResult {
console.log(url);
let answer: UrlMatchResult = url.length === 1 && 
url[0].path.indexOf(pageName) >= 0 ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
    return answer;
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work because the UrlSegment will only give me the path (which is just "Track"), but not the query parameters. Any ideas how I can go around this limitation?

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com

Comment: @CodeMatrix I know this isn't javascript. The backend of the application is Java. I just put it out there to explain why I'm using the query parameters to navigate through pages. In fact, my code up there is TypeScript, not JavaScript.